# Explode mathematical operation with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am creating a math operator for my own language. But I have a lot of problem about regex. I want to split to math signs, numbers and strings.

For example I want to:

```
$val = "2+nfx(2, 5, xy(2+6))";
```

and preg_split result:

```
[0] => 2
[1] => +
[2] => nfx(2, 5, xy(2+6))
```

Comment: what about `xy(2+6)`?

Comment: Regex is not good on nesting, the nested `()` will pose a problem, as it's not just about their format but their order.  You would be better served making a basic lexer instead ...   something like these https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers

Comment: It may also help to know what the current Regex is and how you use it...

Comment: Yes but what is `xy` is it `xy * 2 + 6` or a function call?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix xy is a function. Please don't touch it in parentheses.

Comment: @Wold - I touched it, sorry.  Oh, what is the output you want.  I need more info's

Comment: @Wold to do what you want with that exact equation above you can use: `$arr = preg_split('/(\+)/', $val, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Comment: if you know the operator and just want the first 2 you can just do `strtok($val,'+')`  Or you can just do `explode('+', $val, 2)` but you lose the `+`

Comment: For this particular structure something like `~\w+(\([^()]*(?R)?\))|\d+|[-+/*]~` might do. (There's better options for recursive parens matching of course). And a simple lexer is indeed simpler. You'll likely want to evaluate it anyway, so a shunting-yard implementation might fit better.

Comment: PD of [Regex to match expression with multiple parentheses, one within each other](//stackoverflow.com/q/11193240)

Comment: @mario Thanks for your reply. It's solved my problem.